# How do I edit this perl script so that it outputs a single row per subject instead of two rows?

Tags: perl

I have a file that is an output in the form below per subject:

01:14502 11:15415 01:21265 11:24508 00:25150

The numbers to the left of the colon are then output to a long form file where the 0 is on the first row and the 1 on the 2nd row till column 14502 and so on.

The long form will look like this, displayed in 2 rows per subject:

Row 1:0000000...till 14502, then 111111...till 15415 and so forth till 25150

Row 2:1111111...till 14502, then 111111...till 15415 and so forth till 25150

I want to edit the perl script that outputs the long form so that it only outputs it to 1 row per subject in the form below:

01010101...till 14502, then 111111...till 15415, 010101...till 21265 and so on up to 0000...till 25150.

The perl script that outputs the long form is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

#use strict;

if ((scalar @ARGV) != 2){

print "USAGE::./thisprog.pl <LAMPLD-outfile> <postprocessed-file>\n";
die;

}
my $infile = shift @ARGV;
my $outfile = shift @ARGV;
my @hap1;
my @hap2;

open IN, $infile or die "print cannot open $infile\n";
open OUT, ">$outfile" or die "print cannot open $outfile\n"; 

$count = 0; 
while (my $line = <IN>) {

$line =~ s/^\s+//; 
chomp $line; 
# print "Ind: $count\n";
my @temp =  split /\s+/, $line;
my $start = 0;
undef @hap1;
undef @hap2;
foreach my $bkpt (@temp){
#   print $bkpt."\n";
    my ($pop, $end ) = split /:/, $bkpt;
for (my $i =$start; $i < $end; $i++){
    my @ancs = split //, $pop ;
    push(@hap1, $ancs[0]);
    push(@hap2, $ancs[1]);
}
  $start = $end;
}
print OUT join("",@hap1)."\n";
print OUT join("",@hap2)."\n";

$count++;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

As far as I understand the code, the **@hap1** and **@hap2** are the ones that output it to the two 2 rows in the long form file, so I only want it to output it to one row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is a bit clunky. This will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $infile  or die qq{Cannot open "$infile" for input: $!\n};
open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die qq{Cannot open "$outfile" for output: $!\n};
select $out_fh;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
  my $start = 0;
  for my $item ( split ) {
    my ($pop, $end) = split /:/, $item;
    print $pop x ($end - $start);
    $start = $end;
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked beautifully and gives me exactly what I wanted!